# Allowing just switch ranges in gcc

Tags: debian, dpkg, gcc

I'm trying to clean up some C code and build a Debian package. The makefile was set to use -Wall but debuild uses -Wpedantic .

*As it happens this was "a good thing" as the code was casting data pointers into function pointers (not allowed in ISO C and seriously dangerous ...on some architectures data and code may be in different address spaces)*

However the code also uses ranges in switch statements, these are a gcc (and clang) extension and so -Wpedantic throws a fit.

```
case QNAP_PICSTS_SYS_TEMP_0 ... QNAP_PICSTS_SYS_TEMP_70:
```

(#defines not an enum)

I gather use of switch ranges is common the kernel, I could recode it to use a default with some if/else logic but this will actually be slower (a jump table vs code)

So 1 is there an option to allow just this feature and 2 (for bonus points) how do I set that in the Debian package rules ?

Options are here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Most GCC extensions can't be individually excluded from warnings, as far as I know. I'm skeptical on the performance claims you make: if you converted the whole switch/case/case/default clause to an if/else if/else if/else construct, you should get code that is at least as performant. A jump table that is large because it has to cover many cases is worse than an actual conditional jump. Let your optimizing compiler be smart. You're almost certainly not helping it with a (under the hood when the range is expanded) 70-clause switch. If definitely benchmark both if/else as well as switch.

Comment: Note that hitting an unexpected entry in a jump table is expensive, even if it points to the same destination. Your processor works better if there's less indirections that can be mispredicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the compiler output for switch/case/default where a large range is used; and I compared it to the same code implemented in if/else if/else ([source code](https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/90ceaab835a7eddf849a8d56457c5941)).

It yields the same exact binary code, aside from names ([Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zo4Tq6djP)), when used with the GCC 12.2 as default in debian 12, and with the relevant `dpkg-buildflags` as used by debian.

Luckily, a modern compiler sees simple `if(state == constant) expr; else if(state == other_constant)…` and converts them to jump tables if they're short. So, exact same code as with switch/case. This already happens at `-O1`, so it's not some racy dangerous optimization.

And, furthermore to little surprise, constructs like `case 5 ... 74:` get converted to a comparison with 75 (after cases below 5 have already been handled by a jump table).

So, really, no reason in modern code to use `switch` and `case`, unless you think that `case CONSTANT: … break;` looks cleaner than `if(state == CONSTANT){ … }`. I don't – and I don't think your compiler does, either: having blocks allows for more stringent scoping.

There's one exception, and that is that of course `case:` without `break` allows you to basically emulate `goto` without `goto`:

```c
switch(state) {
case 1: 
  value += 0.2f;
case 2:
  retval = 1.0f/value;
  break
// …
}
```

is equivalent to the hypothetical

```c
if (state == 1) {
  value += 0.2f;
  goto label_in_two;
}
else if(state == 2) 
  label_in_two:
  retval = 1.0f/value;
}
```

(and we both know the bugs that forgetting the `break;` will bring; it's the same issues that using `goto` will bring if you're not *very* careful.)

I hope you see how `switch` is really a convenience construct for people building finite state machines, and not meant to be used with ranges – there's simply no upside with a compiler that's not ancient compared to `if/else if`, and large sources for bugs in non-obvious control flow.

Thus, I think with hindsight being strong and with the knowledge of modern compiler optimizations being good, I'd say that GNU feature of `case` ranges was ill-conceived, and the warning hence sensible.

I therefore come to the conclusion that the correct way of silencing that warning is a conversion of your `switch`/`case`/`default` to an `if`/`else if`/`else` construct.

Comment: I knew I shouldn't have mentioned the jump tables, it was a personal foible (my day job at one time was to write an optimising C compiler, from scratch ..this was while X3J11 were still debating ANSI-C) . Anyhow the code is not mine and I am not the official maintainer. Since it looks like there is no file-grained option (allow-GCC-extensions would be OK) I'll send the maintainer patches for the dangerous pointer casting but I don't feel I can rewrite his code just to avoid a -Wpedantic warning, if he's been OK leaving these in previous releases he probably won't welcome/accept them.

Comment: I do have some views on the if/then/else + case/switch debate but I guess that's a (programming) debate to be had on stackoverflow . Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @GraemeV you're probably right; since both work, it would possibly even be a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, since the code works and actually leads to the exact same results (at least in my simplistic example above).